# Application gets stuck when on release mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, appstore-approval

Greetz,

I am ready to submit an application to the appStore but the problem is the application gets stuck when I build it on release mode (Do I have to build it on release mode in order to submit to appStore?) but it gets stuck while loading the first data that are retrieved from a server. Which means the MBProgressHUD I'm using is just there displayed indefinitely even if some data was already retrieved (I retrieve a JSON string with data and an Image).

The application works and builds perfectly in debug mode, for some reason on release mode it doesn't. I tried to do a rm -rf build on the project and cleaning it aswell to no avail. I tried deleting the application from the simulator and device with no results. Am I doing something wrong, or is it code related? Maybe provisioning?

Thank you!

These are the log messages I get while running on release mode. The application does not crash.

```
[11603:5d03] Starting asynchronous request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x682e800>
[11603:7803] Request #1 will use connection #1
[11603:7803] Request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x682e800> received response headers
[11603:7803] Got a keep-alive header, 
             will keep this connection open for 5.000000 seconds
[11603:7803] Request <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x682e800> finished downloading 
             data (227370 bytes)
[11603:7803] Request #1 finished using connection #1
[11603:7803] Request finished: <ASIHTTPRequest: 0x682e800>
```

And that's it, the application actually finishes the request and retrieves the data successfully but still the MBProgressHUD gets stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was apparently the fault of a while loop. The while was empty purposefully. But when I put a NSLog inside it, the release mode works just fine. Very weird and irregular. I guess release uses some very awkward configuration though it shouldn't.

Comment: This is not irregular. In release mode compiler optimizations are turned off. A while loop may be optimized away, unless it does something with an effect on the outside world. Adding `NSLog()` clearly makes that the loop must stay. Another possibility is that the `NSLog()` changes the exact timing, which is also influenced by build settings.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your explanation. I was then lucky to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

Test the application again for Release mode, is it happening to be crashed?? or simply stucking at some point of execution. What does your log messages say?

Comment: I posted the log on the question. What I see is that the application manages to retrieve the data I need but the loader simply gets stuck on the screen, blocking all user interaction. This does not happen on debug mode. The application is not crashing. It just gets stuck.